# fetchedresultscontroller with two entities - predicate to target each entity?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

My iPhone app has a summary page (UITableView) where I would like to show a quick overview and therefore I need to get info from several entities. It was suggested to create an abstract parent entity and have my two entities as children of this one. This do allow me to fetch the two entities using the one fetchedresultscontroller.

This works but I find that I need to filter the return a small bit. Because of the 'hack' above these entities have nothing in common so I need completely separate predicates.so from EntityA I would need "color = blue" and from EntityB "length >= 10". Because the entity I'm actually querying have none of these this doesn't work at all.

Is there a way to do this or what's the best approach here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Niether the UITableView or the NSFetchedResultsController is designed to deal with more than one entity at a time. Moreover, it seldom makes any sense to try to do so. If you find yourself in such a situation, you probably need to rethink your data model design.

If entities are ***logically*** associated with each other then they should be linked by a relationship. If data from any two objects is to be displayed in the same tableviewCell without being gibberish then they must have some logical association and therefore should be linked by a relationship of some kind. To display in the table, you fetch one side of the relationship and then walk the relationship/s to find the other related objects.

If the logical association is strong, it should be defined as a formal relationship in the data model e.g.:

```
EntityA{
    //... some attributes
    b<-->B.a
}

EntityB{
    //...some attributes
    a<-->A.b
}
```

However, if the relationship is weak or transient, then you should use a [fetched property](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html) to relate them. The fetched property dynamically searches for other entities based on a preprogrammed fetch.

```
EntityA{
    creationDate:date
    someBs--(creationDate=$FETCH_SOURCE.creationDate)-->B
}

EntityB{
    creationDate:date
}
```

A key concept here is that Core Data is providing the entire model layer of your Model-View-Controller design. It is not just a dumb database but an active object graph that models both the data itself and its behavior. Once you have a properly designed data model, problems with the controllers and views resolve themselves automatically.

Comment: Thank you. The two entities I am using here have nothing in common - and shouldn't have. All attempts at fixing this in the model would just make it all a mess. I will have to check if I really need this and if I do just run 2 fetches into an array. Thanks again!

Comment: If the specific objects have nothing in common, why are they being displayed in the same row cell of the tableview? They have to have some relationship otherwise a table makes no sense.

Comment: The data from the 2 entities will not go in to the same cells. I will be displaying overdue activities from entityA, and then suggested activites from entityB - each in their own cells. What I've actually done here is created a new Entity and created fetched properties against the other entities that I need.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly, you can use notifications and send a dictionary of required information to the UITableView view controller class.

Comment: Yes, so all of that I have in the fetchedresultscontroller. The UITableView is getting all in information. I want to use predicates to give it a bit less information. I should have been more clear here, sorry. What I need to know is if it is possible to filter EntityA with predicateA and EntityB with predicateB when fetching ParentEntiry?